# Output not able to show at UI

Tags: android, output

I'm currently trying to write an app to calculate BMI and calories needed by a person (male / female).
My apps have 2 parts:
1. BMI calculation
2. Calories needed

The first part works well (so I excluded the code for this part), but for the 2nd part, calories needed calculation, it is not able to show up the result as expected (after I click on 'calories needed' button). Probably something is still missing but I cant find it so far.

Everything looks fine in the code, no error.
Can anyone help to have a look on it? :) thanks in advance.

Code as below:

```
package com.example.caloriescalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class BMIcalculation extends Activity
{
EditText weightE;
EditText heightE ;
EditText ageE ;
TextView caloriesresult ;
RadioButton male; 
RadioButton female;

Button calories;

EditText weightText ;
EditText heightText ;
EditText ageText;
TextView resultText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.bmilayout_main);     

    weightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
    heightE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
    ageE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ageText);
    caloriesresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriesText);
    male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradio); 
    female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradio);

    Button calories = (Button) findViewById(R.id.caloriesButton); 
    calories.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {
         @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {    
                    int caloriesneed = 0, weight = 0, height = 0, age = 0;

                    try {
                            if ((!weightE.equals("")) && (!heightE.equals("")) && (!ageE.equals(""))) 
                                {
                                weightE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightText);  
                                weight = Integer.parseInt(weightE.getText().toString().trim());     
                                heightE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightText);  
                                height = Integer.parseInt(heightE.getText().toString().trim());
                                ageE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);  
                                age = Integer.parseInt(ageE.getText().toString().trim());

                                    if (male.isSelected()) 
                                        {
                                            caloriesneed = (int) Math.round (655 + 9.6*weight + 1.8*height - 4.7*age);                                       
                                            caloriesresult.setText(caloriesneed);
                                        }

                                    else if (female.isSelected())
                                        {
                                            caloriesneed = (int) Math.round (66 + 13.7*weight + 5*height - 6.8*age);
                                            caloriesresult.setText(caloriesneed);
                                        }
                                }
                         } 
                     catch (Exception k)
                     { System.out.println(k);

                     }

                }
       });
}
```

Comment: Place Logs in your code, or debug points to debug the point of error.

Comment: "it is not able to show up the result as expected" what do you mean by this? is it showing the wrong output or is it showing nothing at all?

Comment: ya..it's showing nothing at the textview place allocated for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> caloriesresult.setText(caloriesneed);

This is problem. In Android if you assign pure int variable to some TextWidget, error will be thrown because Android **will interpret it as resouce id** of stored String in **strings.xml**.

So for this reason you need explicit casting. You can achieve it with concentation or an usage of `String.valueOf(int value)` or `Integer.toString(int value)` method:

```
textWidget.setText(Integer.toString(value)); // best approach
textWidget.setText(String.valueOf(value));
textWidget.setText("" + value);
```

**Note:** This  is absolutely normal behaviour since if you are developing comercial application, usually you want to have support for more languages - and this feature requires localised Strings stored in proper `XML` file(s).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. I just tried with the first approach,but still nothing shows up. I think there's something else missing..

Comment: Oh i just realised there's another problem for the radiobutton use. I should use if(male.isChecked) instead of (male.isSelected).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you try to input an integer to `settext()` which requires a `string` for input parameter, so you can try:

```
caloriesresult.setText("" + caloriesneed);
```

or

```
caloriesresult.setText(Integer.toString(caloriesneed));
```

or

```
caloriesresult.setText(String.valueOf(caloriesneed));
```